# How to use Dataframe data in python script?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello everyone I'm trying to figure out how to pull data from a data frame using pandas inside my new script?

So I've got excel data saved and I use pandas to pull the data into python but how do I use that data pulled to reference?

For example :

> 'start': {
> 'date': '2022-02-22'

with date 11/17/2022 from the excel sheet.

UPDATE: the event data needs to be JSON string so if I turn the data frame into JSON how would I call this in place?

```
data = df.to_json(orient='columns')
print(data)
```

I hope that makes sense? any help would be greatly appreciated!

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
from google_apis import create_service
from pprint import pprint
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl  

service = create_service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

calendar_id_jameson = 'primary'

""""
Create an event
"""
event = {
  'summary': 'Test',
  'description': 'Date 11/17/2022',
```

Comment: You just want to read the data from a cell? Maybe something like df.at[1,'Case_number']?

Comment: well read it but make it a 'callable feature'? I guess is the word. so I can instead of manually type those case numbers and file dates in my event. I can say "use date from excel cell d2"

Comment: You can use df.iat[0,0] where 0,0 are the coordinates for your cell. Of course, you can't use d2 because it is no longer Excell, but df.iat[5,2] should do the same.

Comment: so something like this :description': {df.iat[5,2]},?

Comment: so when I ran the code it states that its not a json string. So if I do data = df.to_json(orient='columns') and turn it into json string how would I call this now?

Comment: I will write an answer, it might be easier to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple different methods from the Pandas data frame to retrieve the information you want. [Here](https://www.stackvidhya.com/get-value-of-cell-from-a-pandas-dataframe/) you can find a comprehensive guide, but if we use `df.iat[x,y]` as an example you can do like this:

```
...
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\phlfo\calendar\Case_Files.xlsx')
...
event = {
  'summary': 'Test',
  'description': f'{df.iat[5,2]}',
...
```

I omitted parts of your code for clarity, but notice that you must give a string to the dictionary under `'description': 'this has to be string'`. Here I used an f-string, it will replace the result from what is between curly brackets into your string.